# Java: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

I developed a small Java program under windows and am now trying to run it on an ubuntu machine.

### run.sh:

```
/opt/atlassian/jira/jre/bin/java -classpath "commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;opencsv-3.3.jar;.\TisowareExportConverter.class" info.aptis.plakon.TisowareExportConverter /home/tisoware/transfer/tisoware_presence_export.csv /home/tisoware/convert/$
```

I compiled the .java file under windows

### Directory contents

```
tisoware@server037:~/convert$ ls -la
insgesamt 472

    drwxr-xr-x 2 root         root           4096 Apr 26 11:51 .
    drwxr-xr-x 7 tisoware     tisoware       4096 Apr 26 11:32 ..
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root         root         412739 Apr 18 15:46 commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root         root            293 Apr 26 11:51 convert.sh
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root         root           1024 Apr 26 11:51 .convert.sh.swp
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root         root            108 Apr 26 10:47 doku.txt
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root         root          31217 Apr 18 15:46 opencsv-3.3.jar
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 root         tisoware          5 Apr 26 11:24 outfile.csv
    -rw-r--r-- 1 aptisSupport aptisSupport    200 Apr 19 14:19 tiso_user_mapping.csv
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root         root           4425 Apr 19 14:21 TisowareExportConverter.class
```

### The java class

```
package info.aptis.plakon;

public class TisowareExportConverter {

    public static void main (String[] args) { /* stuff is done here */}
}
```

### Problem

All I get is

```
tisoware@server037:~/convert$ bash convert.sh
Fehler: Hauptklasse info.aptis.plakon.TisowareExportConverter konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
```

(Translation: Could not find or load main class info.aptis.plakon.TisowareExportConverter)

What am I doing wrong?

Under Windows the program runs like this

### run.bat

```
java -classpath libs\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;libs\opencsv-3.3.jar;out\production\tisowareExportConverter2 info.aptis.plakon.TisowareExportConverter tiso_infile.csv tiso_outfile.csv tiso_user_mapping.csv
```

Thank you, Internet <3

Comment: Maybe `.\TisowareExportConverter.class` in classpath should be `./TisowareExportConverter.class`?

Answer (score -1):

I worked around this problem by packaging the class as a jar like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025607/how-to-create-a-jar-file-or-export-jar-on-intellij-like-eclipse-java-archive-e

Comment: Please do not post answers depending on external links. Put the relevant part into your answer or post the link as a comment to the question. See [answer] for details.